# SQL in DB2 for multiple update with join

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table like this ....
[Table Desc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtTM8.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtTM8.jpg)

Now my job is copy EMAIL_ADDRESS where EMAIL_ADDRESS_ENCRYPT is same for two or more records. 
Can any one help with the SQL... 
I tried with this

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.email_address = Table_B.email_address
FROM
    MEMBER_EMAIL AS Table_A
    INNER MEMBER_EMAIL AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.member_id = Table_B.member_id
```

But this is not working in DB2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That UPDATE ... FROM syntax is vendor specific.

Comment: yes , thats the issue in our case , but what is the solution....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think DB2 supports the `FROM` in updates (in the same way as T-SQL).  You can do this as:

```
UPDATE Table_A
    SET Table_A.email_address = (SELECT Table_B.email_address
                                 FROM Table_B 
                                 WHERE Table_A.member_id = Table_B.member_id
                                )
    WHERE (SELECT 1 FROM Table_B WHERE Table_A.member_id = Table_B.member_id);
```

Comment: `WHERE member_id  IN (SELECT member_id FROM Table_B);` is how I always see it done.  Might not matter.

Comment: @Hogan . . . That works too.  I prefer the parallelism of `exists`, because it uses exactly the same conditions as the correlation conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Though an old one, and there's a condition missing in the question,  nevertheless

How about

```
MERGE INTO MEMBER_EMAIL TABLE_A
USING (
    SELECT TABLE_B.MEMBER_ID, TABLE_B.EMAIL_ADDRESS 
    FROM MEMBER_EMAIL TABLE_B --<i>you can add some WHERE here to (un)complicate things</i>
    ) AS TABLE_C
ON 
TABLE_A.MEMBER_ID = TABLE_C.MEMBER_ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
TABLE_A.EMAIL_ADDRESS = TABLE_C.EMAIL_ADDRESS
;
```